# Chaining outputs in ArcPy standalone script

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, attribute-joins, parameters

I am trying to create a standalone ArcPy script.

I started by creating this in ModelBuilder and then I exported it as a Python script. This works perfectly in ModelBuilder but produces only an empty Shapefile in the standalone script!

The script is pretty simple:

1. Create a layer out of 2 enterprise geodatabase as input to 'Add_Join' tool
2. Join the two layers
3. Create a view out of a standalone table in the same geodatabase
4. join the table view to the result of step 2
5. use 'FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion' to save as shapefile

For some reason I get only an empty shapefile. The final 'FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion' tool does not seem to wait for the joins to complete.

Is a parameter dependency an option here for standalone ArcPy tools?

```
Primary_FeatClass = "C:\\Temp\\PROD_GIS_XS01_NIS.sde\\SchemaName.Electric\\SchemaName.Primary_FeatClass"
FeatClass2 = "C:\\Temp\\PROD_GIS_XS01_NIS.sde\\SchemaName.Electric\\SchemaName.FeatClass2"
Table2 = = "C:\\Temp\\PROD_GIS_XS01_NIS.sde\\SchemaName.Table2"

Field_Map = "INSTALDT \"Installed Date\" true true false 36 Date 0 0 ,First,....<more text>...." << truncated 
 
 
# ----------------Join 2 feature layers---------------
#Feature layer from GDB feature class
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Primary_FeatClass, Primary_FeatClass_Layer, "", "", "OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE....<more text>....") << truncated 

#Feature layer from GDB feature class
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(FeatClass2, FeatClass2_layer, "", "", "OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;....<more text>....") << truncated 

#Add Join them together to create the first_join_result
arcpy.AddJoin_management(Primary_FeatClass_Layer, "RELSUPPORTSTRUCTUREOBJECTID", FeatClass2_layer, "OBJECTID", "KEEP_COMMON")


# ---------------- Join another Table to the above-----------------------
#Make Table View
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(Table2, Table2_View, "", "", "OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;....<more text>....") << truncated 

#Join table view to the first_join_result
arcpy.AddJoin_management(Primary_FeatClass_Layer, "SchemaName.Primary_FeatClass.CISSERVICEACCOUNTNUMBER", Table2_View, "SERVICEACCOUNTASSOCIATIONCD", "KEEP_COMMON")


#--------------- export to Shapefile ----------------------

# Process: Feature Class to Feature Class
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(Primary_FeatClass_Layer, TEMP, "Primary_FeatClass.shp", "", Field_Map, "")
```

Comment: first_join_result is undefined, or set prior to the code sample. What is the value of Primary_FeatClass_Layer? The 2nd parameter should be a string, if you want a layer **Primary_FeatClass_Layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Primary_FeatClass, "Primary_FeatClass_Layer", "", "",...** or you can use the string as a proxy but not all layer operations will work with a string proxy of a layer object. Note that you can use the python window in ArcCatalog to execute line by line and test the resuts with a print statement to see the variables values.

Comment: sorry, i have corrected the error.  "Primary_FeatClass_Layer", is the main feature class i am trying to export after joining another layer and a table in sequence

Comment: Like @MichaelStimson said (both) your makefeaturelayers will fail, and your MakeTableVIew. If you corrected the errors, edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: I was able to resolve my problem by running the geoprocessing modelbuilder-model in python by importing my custom toolbox (as opposed to converting it to standalone script).  My ultimate goal was to use task scheduler to run the model. ref : https://communityhub.esriuk.com/technicalsupport/2016/8/31/scheduling-a-modelbuilder-model-using-task-scheduler